# Is it possible to integrate Google Maps with the directions and the Transit layer into an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, navigation, gtfs

Sorry if this question is obvious for some of you.

I know we can link to the existing Goggle Maps app, but I would like to have an app that does not exit and provides the direction within. I intend using GTFS for public transit.

On the other hand, would it be possible to plot a line inside the iPhone app the results as returned by Google Transit? (say, I send it the arrival and departure addresses)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on integrating direction support in an iPhone app at the moment, and I've found these options:

- Call out to the maps app using a `maps.google.com` URL
- Use the [Google Maps JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/) in a `UIWebView`
- Draw a line in a transparent view overlaid on a `MKMapView`.

I already discounted #3 as infeasible...

Comment: Thank you. Unibus is supposed to do something similar. I had trouble using it though. 
http://sites.google.com/site/zhenwangyao/unibus-ibusuniversal

I try to figure out what is actually feasible :).